# Easy way to get task name by task definition id

Tags: java, business-process-management, camunda

There is a comparatively easy way to get process definition name by key, but I can't find any way (except to just parse BPMNModel) to get task definition name by task definition id (and, for example, process definition id). Does anyone know about something similar?

**EDIT**

I know that I can get task name by task instance (that is, `org.camunda.bpm.engine.task.Task#getName`), but I need to get task name by task definition (that is, I have no instances of `org.camunda.bpm.engine.task.Task`).

Answer (score 2):

With the TaskService you can create a query for tasks by calling its method createTaskQuery(). The created task query object then offers several methods to narrow down the query by passing query parameters, e.g.

- processDefinitionId("") => the id of the process definition deployment the task belongs to
- processDefinitionKey("") => the id of the process definition in the bpmn xml
- taskDefinitionKey("") => the id of the task itself in the bpmn xml

The query then returns either a list() of Task objects or a singleResult() Task. And the Task interface has a method getName():

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskDefinitionKey("myKey").singleResult();
String name = task.getName();
```

Comment: TaskService only works with user task instances that are available in a process instance. I need to get task name out of context of running processes (please see updated question)

Comment: I see. I fear then you have to look into the BpmnModelInstance. At least I am not aware of another possibility.